# Exportint Trac wiki to Confluence using UWC tool

Tags: export, trac

I want to create an Export of Trac Wiki and import it to COnfluence using UWC tool.

All Trac Wiki Pages and Attachments are stored in Postgres Database.

Can anyone please let me know how can i create Trac Export which can be readable by UWC. I am confused about TracEnviorment where can i find this?

Thank You,
Akash

Answer (score 0):

Last thing first: If you don't know about a Trac Environment, you'll hardly be fit for the task you're aiming at right now. Start reading a bit about Trac, that is largely self-documenting, could help. No matter from where, be it the 'TracEnvironment' page in your own Trac wiki or [the authoritative resource](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracEnvironment).

OTOH I'm not familiar at all with UWC, but a bit of research revealed, that Trac wiki is supported by a user-contributed module in UWC. So I guess that [its documentation page](https://migrations.atlassian.net/wiki/display/UWC/UWC+Trac+Notes) is the natural place to start from. From what I've read so far the export/import is file-based and in line with recommendations under `Exporter` on that same page.

Answer (score 0):

First, read https://migrations.atlassian.net/wiki/display/UWC/UWC+Trac+Notes.

Second, for attachments, you may need to use this as a reference http://l33t.peopleperhour.com/blog/2014/07/10/converting-a-trac-wiki-to-confluence/, anyway you will need to adapt it to your actual DBMS behind Trac.

Note that the current UWC - Trac integration is not as polished as someone may expect, so prepare yourself to download UWC source, debug it and patch it.